# Migration Apache flash to adobe air

Tags: flash, migration, air, adobe

We have a requirement to convert an Apache flash based web application which i support from Apache flash to Adobe air as Apache flash, currently application runs on any browser with support of adobe flash player, since Adobe flash is no longer going to be supported after 2020, I have googled on how to create an Adobe AIR project but haven't found much information on internet on what IDE we should use to create an AIR application. please help on answering below queries. Thanks in Advance.

Is targeting AIR a viable solution for this migration?
What is the opensource IDE we should be using to develop AIR based application?
Where can we find documentation to help on such a migration?
What are the difficulties we may face during this migration?
Any other point you may consider of interest in this context

Comment: AIR is Flash Player with desktop benefits (r/w access to local disk, window management, etc.). Hence, AIR app cannot be web-based, I hope you are aware. As for IDE, I think your best shot is **FlashDevelop** as it supports all kinds of Flash projects: web-based, Flex/MXML, AIR, Mobile AIR, and so on. You can create a new project and target AIR with few clicks there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have started using Intellij IDE, where i'm tried to create a air project, but When i try to run the application, it does require flash player, any idea around this?

Comment: You need to install Flash Player, obviously. What kind of workaround might you possibly expect here? "Standalone Content Debugger" one. That's why I pointed to **FlashDevelop**. It handles downloading and installing these things for you via dedicated window component.